# How can I change line color when I use cv::rectangle() in 16bit image?

Tags: c++, opencv

When I use cv::rectangle() in a 16-bit image to draw ROI image, I want change the color of the line. But no matter how I change the para scalar(), the lines it draws are black anyway.
But color change when I draw in a 8-bit image,I dont konw why and how to make the change works.

```
cv::rectangle(LocalImage, cv::Rect(Corners[0], Corners[1]), cv::Scalar(255,255,255), 2);
```

I use this sentence to draw rectangle, it works only with black edge.
Please tell me what difference it has within CV_16U Mat and CV_8U Mat.

Comment: You should provide as much information as possible. What type is 'LocalImage'. Chances are that you try to draw color into a greyscale image. Ensure that you use the appropiate type for the image you want to draw the recatngle into (CV_8UC3). If your image is of another type you can convert it via https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html.

Comment: 255 in 16 bit is quite dark. Try 65535.